# c++ getservbyport returning wrong information

Tags: c++

When I run this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(){
    struct servent* serv = getservbyport(22, "tcp");
    if(serv != NULL){
        std::cout<<"name: "<<serv->s_name<<" type: "<<serv->s_proto<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
name: pcanywherestat type: tcp
```

If I were to run `getservbyport(21, "tcp");` the variable `serv` would return `NULL`.
When I go to the the `/etc/services` file, it includes these lines:

```
ssh              22/udp     # SSH Remote Login Protocol
ssh              22/tcp     # SSH Remote Login Protocol

ftp              21/tcp     # File Transfer [Control]
```

If I search the file for `pcanywherestat` it doesn't exist within the file. Why am I getting this result from running that code?

Comment: `/etc/services` is not the only place on every platform where `getservbyport()` can get its information from. I also find it odd that `getservbyport(21, "tcp")` would return NULL where there is clearly an entry for `ftp` in your `/etc/services` file.

Comment: based on the documentation at https://linux.die.net/man/3/getservbyport it is, I am compiling using g++ on a mac

Comment: From https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Services-Database.html: "*The database that keeps track of “well-known” services is usually either the file `/etc/services` **or an equivalent from a name server**.*" In any case, you are linking to a Linux doc. The Mac version of `getservbyport()` is documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/getservbyport.3.html

Comment: Do you know how to make it get the information from `/etc/services` or what file it is getting its' information from?

Comment: on linux it would be `getent` https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getent.1.html that searches all name dbs, use this to confirm something knows this entry

Comment: `pcanywherestat` typically uses port 5632 on both UDP and TCP, so its odd that it is being found for port 22 instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getservbyport(3)` and family store numeric values in Big Endian (aka, network byte order).  As a result, you need to convert any int's, in this case with `htons()`, thusly:

```
struct servent* serv = getservbyport(htons(22), "tcp");
```

`hton*(3)` convert values between host and network byte order

Edit: the functions `htons`, `htonl`, `htonll` convert from host to `short int`, `long int`, and `long long int`, respectively.

Comment: Ah, makes sense now, as `22` passed in as-is and interpreted in network byte order yields port `5632`, which is `pcanywherestat`'s port. You might want to include a quote from `getservbyport()`'s documentation mentioning this endian requirement